# AWS lambda run Spring batch Job from from request handler with out using scheduler

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-batch

My application is using spring boot with batch and testing it in aws lambda I want run the job in main method and NOT through scheduler. Is it possible to do that?

```
    @SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.myrepo.repository")
@ComponentScan("com.myrepo")
@EnableScheduling
public class Main {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(hMain.class);
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher launcher;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            LOG.info("Start of application - debt card notofication JOB");
            SpringApplication.run(BatchMain.class, args);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception caught bathch Main, );
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT -- I wrote below code but it is not working inside aws lambda function

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0/1 * * * * *")
public void performBatchOpertaion() {
    try {
        LOG.info("Scheduling Job and Launcher {}, {}", job, launcher);
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString(Constants.MYBATCH, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .toJobParameters();
        launcher.run(job, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to schedules ", e.getCause());

    }
}

 public static void startApp() {
        LOG.info("start batch job ");
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
        LOG.info("end batch job ");
    }
```

here is my Request handler class which call statApp() of Main class

```
    --------------------------------------------------------
public class MyHandler implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, String> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    BatchMain main;

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String, Object> input, Context context) {
        LOG.info("Inside the handler request");
        BatchMain.startApp();
        LOG.info("End of handler request");
        return "End Of Application";
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean, run through main? Do you want the job to run once per execution?

Comment: @Compass yes, wants to run job per execution

Comment: I wrote this code for scheduler but it is not working inside aws lambda function. Edited the question

Comment: Implement `CommandLineRunner` and inside the `run()` method you can do `job.execute();`

Comment: @Compass great thanks.

Comment: Your code is correct. It runs the job once. Have you tried to use AWS lamdba scheduling service (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html) to do the scheduling for you instead of trying to write the scheduling the code yourself?

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine, if I use AWS lamdba scheduling service then there is no need to specify the cron scheduler inside code ?

Comment: exactly, your code runs the job once and you don't bother with scheduling code, you let AWS do it for you by configuring your lambda to run according to a cron expression.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine , just check the reference you posted, indeed we can schedule cron job inside lambda function but it will run the lambda function. How it will know to start the batch job ?

Comment: what I understood is that you were able to run your job in AWS lambda but not able to make the scheduling part to work. So I suggested to use the AWS scheduling service. `How it will know to start the batch job ?` This is the role of the  `handleRequest` method of your lambda (which you already wrote).

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine, how do I connect scheduling code to my handler method ? In  aws scheduling service we can only set the time when we want to run the job. How can I pass the Job launcher and Job parameters in aws scheduling service.

Comment: Can you make it clear how to achieve this? Calling main method  from Handler is not working

Answer (score 0):

handleRequestmethod wait until the BatchMain to complete. You can use  Thread join . Lambda execution engine suspend the main thread once the handle request return  the result . In the next event it may complete the previous suspended tasks